# call actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex make a crash

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to put action Sheet to a reuse class, but when i click the action sheet, the app crash and the error is EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

MOTestAction.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MOTestAction : NSObject<UIActionSheetDelegate>
{
    UIActionSheet * actionSheet;
}
- (id) initWithAction;
- (void) showInView:(UIView *) view;
@end
```

MOTestAction.m
    #import "MOTestAction.h"

```
@implementation MOTestAction

- (id) initWithAction
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancle" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

        }
        return self;
    }

- (void) showInView:(UIView *) view
{
    [actionSheet showInView:view];

}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
{

}

@end
```

The caller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically 
    MOTestAction * moActionSheet = [[MOTestAction alloc]initWithAction];
    [moActionSheet showInView:self.navigationController.toolbar];


}
```

Comment: Analyzer with zombies enabled?  Breakpoints on all exceptions?  Anything?

Comment: clickedButtonAtIndex - is an empty definition method?

Comment: Are you retaining your MOTestAction object? The action sheet doesn't retain it's delegate.

Comment: Make action sheet as strong property (or retain below iOS 5.0)

Comment: yes, after run zombies: testaction[1807:f803] *** -[MOTestAction actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6c8a850

Comment: add in UIViewController.h @property(nonatomic, strong) MOTestAction * moActionSheet; and add @synthesize moActionSheet; to UIViewController.m will the solution.